# Import data from csv field into a database field using a lookup table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I wish to import data from a `csv spreadsheet` into an empty database field `named "parishname"` that normally uses a lookup table to add data using the query -

`SELECT "Parish"."parid","Parish"."parishname" FROM "Parish" ORDER BY 2`.

Can someone give me the code required to amend the query to allow data in the csv field to bypass the query. I have little or no MYSQL knowledge and am using Appgini software to build the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Parish,parid,Parish,parishname FROM Parish ORDER BY 2.


if  not work then tell me more and proper  description of your question
```

Comment: The SELECT expression is as displayed by Appgini. I have a main table with the field name 'parishname' and a lookup table called 'Parish' with two fields a) 'parid' (integer 2, autoincrement, unsigned) and b) 'parishname' (VAR 20). The field in the main table is not being filled with text from the csv file probably because it is looking for an integer data type. I need a work round.